# Jenkins Build Error - Unable to determine if resource exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, glassfish

When I try and build my project in Jenkins I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Artifact: org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-api:jar:7.0.19 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:7.0.19 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.11 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.11 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.11 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.11 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.3 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.2.0-b10 has no file.
[ERROR] Unable to determine if resource org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-api:jar:7.0.19:provided exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
[ERROR] Unable to determine if resource org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:7.0.19:provided exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
[ERROR] Unable to determine if resource org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.11:compile exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
[ERROR] Unable to determine if resource org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.11:compile exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
[ERROR] Unable to determine if resource org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.11:compile exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project LDAPTool: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

I then modified my POM file to include `<distributionManagement>` tags. I added the following block to my POM file

```
<distributionManagement>
<downloadUrl>http://repo.release.xxx.corp/main/repo/</downloadUrl>
<repository>
    <id>release-main</id>
    <name>Main Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.release.xxx.corp/main/repo</url>
</repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

But I still get the following error

```
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) 
on project LDAPTool: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact LDAPTool:LDAPTool:war:0.0.1-     20130829.191823-1 from/toxxx-release-main (http://repo.release..corp/main/repo): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.release.xxx.corp/main/repo/LDAPTool/LDAPTool/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LDAPTool-0.0.1-20130829.191823-1.war. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

I then configured the settings.xml file to include the username and password but still get the error. Could someone guide me as to what a solution could be.

Comment: It seems like you are deploying snapshots to a release repository. Have you defined a <snapshotRepository> section ? Some other things that could go wrong: need of a proxy of typo in settings.xml. Tip: try running maven from outside jenkins, i.e. on a terminal as the same user running jenkins. Also add the -X option to maven to get more information about what it does.

Comment: I didn't add a <snapshotRepository> section. I added one and it is working fine. Thank you.